# Are some laptops running better on windows than on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, performance

I have the following issue. I have one laptop **Asus K556U** and one **Acer Laptop** that is with a *lower specifications than the Asus*.

- The asus laptop is with fresh copy of Ubuntu 16.04
- The Acer is with Windows 10

The lower spec laptop is flying in windows and the other one is not slower but its kind of lag in **IntelliJ** .

For example when you are typing in the Ubuntu UI is not "fluent".

But when I execute some program it is **started faster on the Laptop with the ubuntu**.

I am not having a issue using it this way but I'm just wondering. I have all proper drivers.

```
Asus :
Processor Type: Intel Core i7 7500U
Processor Core: Dual Core Processor 7th Generation
Memory: 8 GB RAM
Storage: 1 TB Hard Drive
Video Card: GeForce 940mx
Graphic : 2 GB
It have SSD

and 

Acer :
Processor Type: Pentium Quad Core Processor n3710
Video Card: Nvidia GeForce 920M
Graphic: 2GB
Memory: 8 GB DDR3 
1 TB HD
It have SSD also
```

Comment: IntelliJ....a monstrous java based program that does not run fast.

Comment: @Melebius Done.

Comment: @rtaft I would seriously upvote that comment if you posted it.

Comment: "For example when you are typing in the Ubuntu UI is not "fluent"." is not a problem with hardware. "IntelliJ"  can't you get rid of that? ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind Unfortunately no: )

Comment: The Asus has a GeForce 940MX to which the recommended driver is currently 430.26. This version isn't available in the 16.04 repos. To obtain it you can add the graphics drivers PPA.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia  Thank you a lot.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Actually that was the problem after installed version 430.26 of the drivers its working like it should its not laggy anymore. Thanks again.

Comment: @BorisBorovski It seems like you're not comparing the same software on both machines. What happens when you use IntelliJ on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to justly compare, all recommended drivers should be installed in the laptop running Ubuntu (Asus).

The laptop requires additional, proprietary, Nvidia drivers for the graphics card. At the time of this writing the version to install is 430.

Answer (score 0):

> The lower spec laptop is flying in windows and the other one is not slower but its kind of lag in IntelliJ

That is unlikely to be a hardware issue. More like Java related.

> Are some laptops running better on windows than on Ubuntu

Yes, if not just for the simple fact Microsoft makes and commissions hardware too.

In general we use generic drivers. We also tend to have proprietary drivers for some hardware (mainly graphics card and the NIC). In my experience if there is new hardware (so hardware not based on an already available chip set) it takes about 6 to 8 months for the hardware to get support in Linux. Someone likely needs to examine the specifications of the chip set or get their hands on that specific hardware to run tests.

Then there is just a couple of things to take into account: though Microsoft is a software manufacturer they also created hardware and also pay hardware manufacturers to support features they want. In both cases they do not care for the Linux user. So do not expect a Microsoft Surface to be 100% compatible.

On the other hand: Linux/Ubuntu runs on a lot more older hardware than Windows does. Microsoft will tell you to purchase a new machine almost always when they release a new Windows. We have several flavors that have very low system requirements. Again largely due to us using generic drivers: if a chip set is supported it just works. A couple of times Canonical decided to remove hardware support from the main Ubuntu but the other flavours up to now always picked those up.